# How to redirect to route from included files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im having trouble with redirecting to a different route from a required JavaScript file. As you see in oauth2.js i have a function *validate* which is called when callback from the request.post() method is called. This means I cant pass the express-instantiation (app) as a parameter.

server.js

```
var app = require('express);
var login = require('./routes/login');
app.use('/login', login);

var oauth2 = require('./oauth2');
oauth2.auth();

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('./public/login.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

routes/login.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    module.exports = function (){
        router.get('/login', function(req, res){
            console.log('Logging in...');
        }
        return router;
    }
```

oauth2.js

```
...
var request = require('request');
request.post({
    uri: uri, 
    headers:headers, 
    body:data
}, validate);

function validate(err, res, body){
    ...

    // REDIRECT TO /login.html
}
```

How can I redirect to /login.html from the validate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a middleware to grab the response object of express and use it when oauth2 returns a result:

```
var app = require('express);
var login = require('./routes/login');
app.use('/login', login);

var oauth2 = require('./oauth2');

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  oauth2.auth(function (err, res, body) {
    // validate
    res.redirect('/login');
  });
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('./public/login.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

and your oauth2.js should receive a callback:

```
// some code..  

function auth (cb) {
  // some code ..
  request.post({
      uri: uri, 
      headers:headers, 
      body:data
  }, cb);
  // some code ..
}

// some code ..
```